# Null value for column when selecting using dot or bracket notation but not when using UDF

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to clean up some nested data and extract the fields I care about.

My schema for the nested value is:

```
 |-- maritalstatus: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- text_: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- text__extensions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- extension: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I want to extract the `text_` field as its own column.

I have tried:
`df.select(col("maritalstatus.text_")).show()`
and `df.select(col("maritalstatus")["text_"]).show()` but it returns:

```
+-----+
|text_|
+-----+
| null|
| null|
 ...
| null|
+-----+
```

When I define a UDF as:

```
def getMaritalStatus(ms):
    return ms.text_
gms = udf(getMaritalStatus, StringType())
```

and do `df.select(gms(col("maritalstatus")).show()` it returns the data that i expect

Interestingly, I have another nested struct field that has a similar structure but with numbers as keys instead of names, and I *am* able to use the `df.select(col("birthdate")["0"]).show()` notation

Birthdate's schema:

```
root
 |-- birthdate: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 0: date (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 1: integer (nullable = true)
```

Is there anyway to extract `maritalstatus.text_` without using the UDF? I've heard UDF is not as performant as other approaches?

cassandra table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.patient (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    active boolean,
    active_extensions list<text>,
    address list<frozen<address>>,
    birthdate frozen<tuple<date, int>>,
    birthdate_extensions list<text>,
    communication list<frozen<patient_communication>>,
    contact list<frozen<patient_contact>>,
    contained list<frozen<tuple<text, text, text>>>,
    deceasedboolean boolean,
    deceasedboolean_extensions list<text>,
    deceaseddatetime frozen<tuple<timestamp, text, int>>,
    deceaseddatetime_extensions list<text>,
    extension list<text>,
    gender text,
    gender_extensions list<text>,
    generalpractitioner list<text>,
    identifier list<frozen<identifier>>,
    implicitrules text,
    implicitrules_extensions list<text>,
    language text,
    language_extensions list<text>,
    link list<frozen<patient_link>>,
    managingorganization text,
    maritalstatus frozen<codeableconcept>,
    meta frozen<meta>,
    modifierextension list<text>,
    multiplebirthboolean boolean,
    multiplebirthboolean_extensions list<text>,
    multiplebirthinteger int,
    multiplebirthinteger_extensions list<text>,
    name list<frozen<humanname>>,
    photo list<frozen<attachment>>,
    telecom list<frozen<contactpoint>>,
    text_ frozen<narrative>
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

and the `codeableconcept` is

```
CREATE TYPE keyspace.codeableconcept (
    extension list<text>,
    text_ text,
    text__extensions list<text>,
    id text,
    coding list<frozen<coding>>
);
```

Comment: is it possible to provide some sample data?

Comment: what version of Spark & Spark Cassandra connector is used? And also, Cassandra version

Comment: open source Cassandra 3.11.9, spark-3.0.1, and spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0. I'm running pyspark with the command: 
pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0 --conf spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions

Answer (score 0):

#using pyspark sql
you can query nested data using "." and for array use explode function.

df=df.select("maritalstatus.*").show(1,False)

or

df=df.select("martialstatus.text_").alias("text_new").show(1,False)

Comment: when I do the first one, it "explodes" the data like I want, but if i try to do a further select to get just the `maritalstatus.text_` field, it becomes null:
`df.select("maritalstatus.*").show(1)`
```
+----+--------------------+-----+----------------+---------+
|  id|              coding|text_|text__extensions|extension|
+----+--------------------+-----+----------------+---------+
|null|[[, http://termin...|    S|              []|       []|
+----+--------------------+-----+----------------+---------+
```
rawPatient.select("maritalstatus.*").select("text_").show(1) is null

Comment: @Harrison T can you try the second one? Also if you can share a sample data that will be precise to work on.

Comment: the second fails immediately.  I'm pulling the data from Cassandra using spark-cassandra-connector so I'm not sure if there is a good way to share data easily?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[name]` to access nested values in the column, or you can use `.getItem` function to do the same.  Column could be either explicitly wrapped into `col`, or you can use syntax `dataframe[column_name]` instead.  If we take sample data, like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

rdd = sc.parallelize([('{"maritalstatus": {"id": "some_id", "text_": "some_text", "text__extensions": ["1", "2"], "extension": ["e1", "e2"]}}')])
df = spark.read.json(rdd)
```

then all three calls:

```py
df.select(df['maritalstatus']['text_']).show()
df.select(col('maritalstatus')['text_']).show()
df.select(col('maritalstatus').getItem('text_')).show()
```

will produced the same result:

```
+-------------------+
|maritalstatus.text_|
+-------------------+
|          some_text|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the reply. I can confirm that these all work when I use the JSON like you did, but that syntax still does not work for the 'marital status' field of my patient. I'm pulling the data from Cassandra using spark-cassandra-connector so I'm not sure if there is a good way to share data easily?

Comment: Can you share the structure of your table - just update the question , I didn’t try it with Cassandra, as I didn’t have access to server today